# TabBarController in SubView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

In my MainWindow.xib, I have a the following structure:

```
-Files Owner
-First Responder
-MyApp App Delegate
-Window
-Tab Bar Controller
--Tab Bar
--Selected Recipes Nav Controller (recipes) - The class is set to a subclass of UINavigationController
--Other tabs…
```

I have details view for editing which contains tabs for each of the sections which can be edited, so the structure looks like this:

```
-Files Owner
-First Responder
-Tab Bar Controller
--Tab Bar
--Selected View Controller (recipes) - The class is set to a subclass of UINavigationController
---Scroll View
----UITextField (txtName)
----UITextField (txtDescription)
--Other tabs…
```

When the user clicks the add toolbar button on the main navigation controller, I want to push this new view onto the stack, but I get an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key txtName.'

I believe this could be caused by having two tab controllers. I've tried the following to show the new details view, but all throw the same exception:

```
MyAppAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//[delegate.recipesNavController pushViewController:recipeDetailViewController animated:YES]; //- fails 
//[delegate.rootController presentModalViewController:recipeDetailViewController animated:YES]; //- fails
[self presentModalViewController:recipeDetailViewController animated:YES]; //- also fails
```

**EDIT:** I'm not so sure now, as replacing it with a UISegmentedControl results in a similar error:

> this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key
>   generalScroller.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was declaring the view controller incorrectly. I was using:

```
RecipeDetailViewController *dvController = [[RecipeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeDetailEditView" bundle:nil];
```

When I needed:

```
RecipeDetailEditViewController *dvController = [[RecipeDetailEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeDetailEditView" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key), it seems to have helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009904/linking-label-to-iboutlet-gives-nsunknownkeyexception) too.

Comment: Thanks, but the classes seem to be set up as described.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS error messages are usually pretty to-the-point: what class is it saying is not KV compliant?  Somewhere you're setting up a KVO with txName and/or generalScroller and something is either not listening for those or is listening for a mis-spelled key name.